# 14.04 - Unable to connect Windows PPTP VPN

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, pptp

I am trying to connect a **Windows PPTP VPN**. I created VPN connection through the Network configuration in the Settings. I configured VPN credentials such as **gateway**, **username** and **password**. **Nothing happens** when I enable VPN connection as it can be seen from the pic below:

[image: vpn configuration]

Do I need to install any extra packages in order to connect a Windows PPTP VPN?

***p.s. I am able to connect this VPN through Windows***.

**Edit:** Output of `tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep pptp`

```
Apr  1 15:36:33 talha-monster NetworkManager[820]: <info> Starting VPN service 'pptp'...
Apr  1 15:36:33 talha-monster NetworkManager[820]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 4588
Apr  1 15:36:33 talha-monster NetworkManager[820]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' appeared; activating connections
Apr  1 15:36:39 talha-monster NetworkManager[820]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' disappeared
```

Comment: First in terminal run command `tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep pptp` then tray to connect to vpn. Put output like edit on question.

Comment: edited the post & added the output of syslog

Comment: Next step will be in connecting to vpn server will be `Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.` Try to install them. `sudo apt-get install network-manager-pptp` and `sudo apt-get install network-manager-pptp-gnome`

Comment: it says they are already newest versions.

Comment: Ok, go in Network Manager and edit vpn connection. On pptp advanced option check `mppe`, `mschap`, `mschap2` and all other options.

Comment: all options are already checked

Answer (score 0):

Try to make vpn connection with this script, not with NM.

Maybe on this way all will work.

Create file with some name and put in

```
nano name_of_script
```

script

```
#!/bin/bash
function routeadd {
    route add -host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev ppp0
    route add -net xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx dev ppp0
}
function makepptp {
   echo pty \"pptp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --nolaunchpppd\" >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
   echo remotename PPTP >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
   echo require-mppe-128 >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
   echo file /etc/ppp/options.pptp >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
   echo ipparam vpn >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
pppd call vpn &
}
if [ -a /etc/ppp/chap-secrets ];
        then
        rm /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
    echo $1 PPTP $2 '*' >> /etc/ppp/chap-secrets;
else
    echo $1 PPTP $2 '*' >> /etc/ppp/chap-secrets;
fi

if [ -e /etc/ppp/peers/vpn ];
    then
    rm /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
    echo name $1 >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
    makepptp;
    sleep 8;
    routeadd;
else
    echo name $1 >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
    makepptp;
    sleep 8;
    routeadd;
fi
```

In script change you host ip and add network or/and host witch you wish to connect via vpn

Usage:

```
sudo /path_to_script/name_of_script username password
```

note: set execute permision to script